# how to put a html page in a spring mvc project

Tags: html, ajax, spring, templates, spring-mvc

I have a html ajax web page template and i want to do a web application.
I want to use that template in my spring mvc project and i want to know how can i make that template become a jsp so i can use it in my spring mvc project, what tutorials should i read?, or if this is possible?.

What i want is to make this template work in my spring mvc project.

How can i put all those "html-with ajax" in my views folder with and .jsp extension and make them work.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to [understand about ViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-viewresolver). Requests are [mapped by URL patterns into Spring controller's method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods), and these method returns a view name (sometime a direct view). This view name then gets resolved into actual view by ViewResolver.

A common ViewResolver to configure on your Spring project is the InternalResourceViewResolver which allows you to use jsp view (provided your container supports it). Then you can [use JSP tag to build page templating](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/02/html-page-template-using-jsp-tag/).